# How to use ascii art in c++ to print out art to the screen

Tags: c++

I was looking for any way to convert a file which has ASCII art or any other way.
I saw a program online but there was an error with the reader.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E1776   function "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits> &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 879 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\fstream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function  CA  C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Semester 5\Game Programming\CA\CA\Event.cpp  17

Any help is appreciated

```
string Art:: getArt(ifstream File)
{
    string Lines = "";        //All lines

    if (File)                      //Check if everything is good
    {
        while (File.good())
        {
            string TempLine;                  //Temp line
            getline(File, TempLine);        //Get temp line
            TempLine += "\n";                      //Add newline character

            Lines += TempLine;                     //Add newline
        }
        return Lines;
    }
    else                           //Return error
    {
        return "ERROR File does not exist.";
    }
}

void Art::yo()
{
    ifstream Reader("Orc1.txt");
    string  readArt = getArt(Reader);
}
```

Comment: What is the "error"?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error (active) E1776 function "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits> &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 879 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\fstream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function CA C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Semester 5\Game Programming\CA\CA\Event.cpp 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `std::ifstream`s or `std::ofstream`s by value. You need to pass them by reference:

```
std::string Art:: getArt(std::ifstream& File)
```